# Transcribing sound files to text in python and google speech api

Tags: python, speech-to-text

I have a bunch of files in wav. I made a simple script to convert them to flac so I can use it with the google speech api. Here is the python code:

```
import urllib2
url = "https://www.google.com/speech-api/v1/recognize?client=chromium&lang=en-US"
audio = open('somefile.flac','rb').read()
headers={'Content-Type': 'audio/x-flac; rate=16000', 'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
request = urllib2.Request(url, data=audio, headers=headers)
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
print response.read()
```

However I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "transcribe.py", line 7, in <module>
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 392, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 410, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 370, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1194, in https_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPSConnection, req)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1161, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 32] Broken pipe>
```

I thought at first that it was because the file is too big. But I recorded myself for 5 seconds and it still does the same.

I dont think google ha released the api yet so it's hard to understand why its failing.

Is there any other good speech-to-text api out there that can be used in either Python or Node?

----- Editing for my attempt with requests:

```
import json
import requests
url = 'https://www.google.com/speech-api/v1/recognize?client=chromium&lang=en-US'
data = {'file': open('file.flac', 'rb')}
headers = {'Content-Type': 'audio/x-flac; rate=16000', 'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
r = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
# r = requests.post(url, files=data, headers=headers) ## does not work either
# r = requests.post(url, data=open('file.flac', 'rb').read(), headers=headers) ## does not work either
print r.text
```

Produced the same problem as above.

Answer (score 0):

The API Accepts HTTP POST requests. You're using a HTTP GET Request here. This can be confirmed by loading the URI in your code directly into a browser:

```
HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL

Error 405
```

Also, i'd recommend using the `requests` python library. See http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file

Lastly, it seems that the API only accepts segments up to 15 seconds long. Perhaps your error is the file is too large? If you can upload an example flac file, perhaps we could diagnose further.

Comment: That is a good point, I tried that code but I got the same broken pipe thing: 

(this part does not accept code, check the top)